# Quarkus Scheduler @Scheduled not performing well withproperty "concurrentExecution = ConcurrentExecution.SKIP"

Tags: concurrency, quarkus, scheduler

Hi I am using Quarkus Scheduler with @Scheduled annotation. In this I am giving a property -- "concurrentExecution = ConcurrentExecution.SKIP".
Ideally using this property the scheduler must not get invoked concurrently. But I can see on my cluster , for the same application instance two threads are invoking this scheduler [executor-thread-0] and [executor-thread-1]. Can someone pls help quickly.

In my local when I run this, the thread name shows - [vert.x-worker-thread-0]
Why there is change in the thread names - local vs deployment.

Thanks in advance.

Ideally using this property the scheduler must not get invoked concurrently. But I can see on my cluster , for the same application instance two threads are invoking this scheduler [executor-thread-0] and [executor-thread-1].